# Something wrong encoding using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, encoding, batch-file, utf-8

I have a bat file where I encode some CSV files to UTF-8, and then import the files to a SQLite database.
This is the code I have:

```
echo Codificando ficheros...
powershell -Command "&{ param($Path); (Get-Content $Path) | Out-File $Path -Encoding UTF8 }" CSVs\\prefijo.csv
powershell -Command "&{ param($Path); (Get-Content $Path) | Out-File $Path -Encoding UTF8 }" CSVs\\materiales.csv
powershell -Command "&{ param($Path); (Get-Content $Path) | Out-File $Path -Encoding UTF8 }" CSVs\\zonas.csv
powershell -Command "&{ param($Path); (Get-Content $Path) | Out-File $Path -Encoding UTF8 }" CSVs\\responsables.csv
powershell -Command "&{ param($Path); (Get-Content $Path) | Out-File $Path -Encoding UTF8 }" CSVs\\lideres.csv
powershell -Command "&{ param($Path); (Get-Content $Path) | Out-File $Path -Encoding UTF8 }" CSVs\\pass.csv
powershell -Command "&{ param($Path); (Get-Content $Path) | Out-File $Path -Encoding UTF8 }" CSVs\\capacidadLotes.csv
powershell -Command "&{ param($Path); (Get-Content $Path) | Out-File $Path -Encoding UTF8 }" CSVs\\boletosIndirectos.csv
@echo OFF
echo Generando fichero de base de datos _datosPrecargados.db...
.\sqlite3.exe BaseDatos\_datosPrecargados.db < Sentencias_sql\Sentencias_DatosPrecargados.sql
@echo OFF
echo Generando fichero de base de datos _inventario.db...
.\sqlite3.exe BaseDatos\_inventario.db < Sentencias_sql\Sentencias_Inventario.sql
pause
```

Before I set the PowerShell lines to encode the files it worked fine. But before encoding I have a problem.
The data base seems to be ok but when I do a select sentence looking for the first column of the first record, it is not found.

E.G.
Table "zones":

```
zone     name
----     ----
Z001     Zone 1
Z002     Zone 2
Z002     Zone 3
```

If I execute the sentence `"SELECT * FROM zones"`, it lists all the records, ok.

If I execute the sentence `"SELECT * FROM zones WHERE zone="Z002""`, the record is listed, ok.

But if I execute the sentence `"SELECT * FROM zones WHERE zone="Z001""`, the record is not found.

If I don't set the PowerShell line in the bat file, it doesn't happens and it works fine, but I need to encode the files because I have special characters inside the CSV files like "ñ" or "ó".

I don´t know what can I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm thinking some non-printable chars are being stored in there, it might be storing the BOM data in there. I wonder if more than 4 is returned from `Select LEN(zone) as Length From zones where name='Zone 1'`

Comment: thats right, i get one character more than i can see, I hace tried encoding with ASCII and the problem dissapear but i am not able to use special characters ;(

Comment: i am going to try with other encode types

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you use notepad++ and save one as UTF8 (no BOM) and one with UTF8 (with BOM) and import both and see if the one without BOM is OK or not.

Comment: it works, is the first thing i though, but it have to be a bat file and the csv are generated with excel

Answer (score 0):

If the characters in the files were broken before, transcoding won't fix them, so your PowerShell calls are unlikely to help with the underlying problem. I rather suspect that you need to change your codepage instead:

```
chcp 1251 >nul
```

The command changes the codepage of the current console (i.e. the current `CMD` instance) to the given value (see the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490874.aspx)). `>nul` is just to suppress the output, which is inconsequential to the rest of the script.

Comment: ok, so it means that it does not affect once the bat ends, right?

Comment: sorry but after try this it doesnt works :(, happend the same

Answer (score 0):

Before you do the import make sure both the console and the [files are encoded in what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887398/how-to-bulk-convert-unicode-file-names-to-ascii-file-names-windows-cmd-or-powers/41889138#41889138)

Copy and past the script in your Powershell windows

```
 foreach($FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever in get-childitem)
 {
    $FileName = $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever.Name

    $TempFile = "$($FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever.Name).ASCII"

    get-content $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever | out-file $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever -Encoding ASCII 

    remove-item $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever

    rename-item $TempFile $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever

    write-output $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever "converted to ASCII ->" $TempFile
}
```

---

I would also set your encoding on the console, if you follow the link below

[How to bulk convert unicode file names to Ascii file names windows CMD or powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887398/how-to-bulk-convert-unicode-file-names-to-ascii-file-names-windows-cmd-or-powers/41889138#41889138)