# How to bulk convert unicode file names to Ascii file names windows CMD or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, unicode, command-line

Problem: For some odd reason, the **windows zip util will not zip *up* folders with Unicode file names**. So, I need to convert a large set of filenames (not the contents) to ASCII files names. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820749/powershell-keeps-converting-to-ascii) discuss content conversion

[image: Cannot compress files with UNICODE names]

**How do I mass/bulk convert/rename the file name itself in windows CMD line or Power Shell.** I don't care about what the outputfile name has extra1 etc.

```
//While this changes the content inside the file. it does not rename my file name!

  COPY /Y UniHeader.txt Unicode_Output.txt
  CMD /U /C Type ANSI_Input.txt >> Unicode_Output.txt
```

Comment: Your *best* choice is going to be to find a third-party compression utility that handles Unicode file names.  Writing code to rename the files, while not too difficult, is still more trouble than it is worth - particularly since it will leave you with an archive that is of relatively little use, because the file names bear no relationship to their contents.

Comment: ok thanks I am trying 7zip with better luck, but it also crashes. the names of the files dont matter, because they're going to be served up as guids anyway.

Comment: Unicode - Ascii conversion is highly untrivial a task. You might have some luck with [removing the diacritics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net), but this error prone. Morale: never, ever, use non-ASCII characters in file names. (My mother tongue has diacritics, so I've been dealing with such a probelms since the 80's...)

Comment: @vonPryz that was funny :) but I got it resolved finally, yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, since I am not a powershell guy clearly... but it worked, and [I am sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105022/unicode-in-powershell-with-python-alternative-shells-in-windows?rq=1)!!

1. Goto the Dir you want `cd c:\MyDirectoryWithCrazyCharacterEncodingAndUnicode`
2. Fire this script away!

Copy and past the script in your Powershell windows

```
     foreach($FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever in get-childitem)
     {
        $FileName = $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever.Name    
        $TempFile = "$($FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever.Name).ASCII"    
        get-content $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever | out-file $TempFile -Encoding ASCII     
        remove-item $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever    
        rename-item $TempFile $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever
        # only if you want to debug
        # write-output $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever "converted to ASCII ->" $TempFile
    }
```

While searching I also found out how to fix the encoding for others, for people who keep getting output encoding to ASCII or Unicode [all the time,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820749/powershell-keeps-converting-to-ascii?noredirect=1&lq=1) you can set output [encoding to whatever encoding you want *from Microsoft blog* `$OutputEncoding`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/11/outputencoding-to-the-rescue/)

Issues [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684793/powershell-batch-change-files-encoding-to-utf-8?rq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom?rq=1), [3 for bulk Hex to Ascii just replace the file names with variable you want to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762760/convert-hex-to-ascii-in-powershell/41763171#41763171)

Comment: This is incorrect, it only modifies the file content, not the file name.

Comment: Just tried it on a sample folder, and got "path not found" errors on the folder name containing a trailing single quote (’).

Answer (score 0):

```
$nonascii = [regex] "[^\x00-\x7F]"

Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory+!System | Rename-Item -NewName {
  '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace $nonascii, ''), $_.Extension
}
```

This removes all the non-ascii characters from all the filenames inside the directory.

If you don't want to lose any characters, you can add a transliteration mapping using extra replace statements:

```
$nonascii = [regex] "[^\x00-\x7F]"

Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory+!System | Rename-Item -NewName {
  '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace 'à', 'a' -replace 'é', 'e' -replace $nonascii, ''), $_.Extension
}
```